# Javascript Dynamic Data binding code not working

Tags: javascript, data-binding

I am writing code that uses data binding to change the `innerHTML` of an `span` to the input of the user, but I can't get it to work. What it should do is show the input on the right side of the input field on both the input fields, but it doesn't. Can someone please help me out.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Frontend Framework</title>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" bit-data="name"/>
        <span bit-data-binding="name" style="margin-left: 1rem;"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Lastname:</label>
        <input type="text" bit-data="LastName"/>
        <span bit-data-binding="LastName" style="margin-left: 1rem;"></span>
    </div>
<script src="frontend-framework.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
const createState = (stateObj) => {
  return new Proxy(stateObj, {
    set(target, property, value) {
      target[property] = value;
      render();
      return true;
    }
  });
};

const state = createState({
  name: '',
  lastName: ''
});

const listeners = document.querySelectorAll('[bit-data]');

listeners.forEach((element) => {
  const name = element.dataset.model;
  element.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    state[name] = element.value;
    console.log(state);
  });
});

const render = () => {
  const bindings = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[bit-data-binding]')).map(
    e => e.dataset.binding
  );
  bindings.forEach((binding) => {
    document.querySelector(`[bit-data-binding=${binding}]`).innerHTML = state[binding];
    document.querySelector(`[bit-data=${binding}]`).value = state[binding];
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Mauro0294/g3170whc/4/

Comment: _"Can someone please help me out"_ - The browser does this already. In the console. With an error message: `TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to the fiddle to get the desired result. The problem was with your logic to refer the elements using the `dataset` attributes, so I tried to simplify it.

Some notable changes :

1. Updated the `data-bit` to use `lastName` instead of `LastName`. Made it same as your state.
2. Used `getAttribute` to get the value of the `data-*` properties to correctly get the reference.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```js
const createState = (stateObj) => {
  return new Proxy(stateObj, {
    set(target, property, value) {
      target[property] = value;
      render();
      return true;
    }
  });
};

const state = createState({
  name: '',
  lastName: ''
});

const listeners = document.querySelectorAll('[bit-data]');

listeners.forEach((element) => {
  const name = element.getAttribute('bit-data');
  console.log('here', element.getAttribute('bit-data'), JSON.stringify(element.dataset))
  element.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    state[name] = element.value;
    console.log(state);
  });
});

const render = () => {
  const bindings = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[bit-data-binding]')).map((e) => {
   return e.getAttribute('bit-data-binding');
  });
  //console.log('bindings:', bindings, document.querySelectorAll('[bit-data-binding]'));
  (bindings ?? []).forEach((binding) => {
    document.querySelector(`[bit-data-binding=${binding}]`).innerHTML = state[binding];
    document.querySelector(`[bit-data=${binding}]`).value = state[binding];
  });
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Frontend Framework</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" bit-data="name"/>
        <span bit-data-binding="name" style="margin-left: 1rem;"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Lastname:</label>
        <input type="text" bit-data="lastName"/>
        <span bit-data-binding="lastName" style="margin-left: 1rem;"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is this part:

```
const bindings = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[bit-data-binding]')).map(
    e => e.dataset.binding
  );
```

or more specifically `e.dataset.binding`. Your elements do not a have `data-binding` attribute, which would be the prerequisite for using `dataset.binding`. You can use `e.getAttribute('bit-data-binding')` instead.

But your logic is also flawed: As it currently stands, entering text into an input is pointless, as the state is never updated.

Finally, note that you spell `LastName` with a capital `L` in your DOM but lowercased in your state object.